# Is a trigonometric function applied to a rational multiple of $\pi$ always algebraic?

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-numbers

Specifically, just to talk about cosine, is it true that $\cos(\frac{a\pi}{b})$ is algebraic for integers $a$ and $b$? Looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692370/calculating-arbitrary-sines-cosines) post and the link to trigonometric constants in the comments, it seems likely that this is true. But most of the values calculated there are the result of sum/difference of angle formulas for existing algebraic values of sine and cosine.

This came up when looking at $\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})$. If this is algebraic, how can we calculate it? If it is not, for which arguments will sine and cosine be algebraic and for which arguments will they be transcendental?

Comment: "This question has been asked before" XD.

Comment: @Xam, yeah right? :P But the newer one did get more attention and some really good answers, so ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $z=\cos\frac{a\pi}b+i\sin\frac{a\pi}b=e^{\frac{a\pi i}{b}}$. Then $z^{2b}=1$ and hence $z$ is algebraic. Finally $\cos\frac{a\pi}b=\frac12(z+z^{-1})$ is also algebraic.

Answer (score 4):

To prove that $\cos\frac\pi7$ is algebraic:

Using the sum formulae a bunch of times, calculate $\cos7x$ as a polynomial in terms of $\cos x$. (It turns out that $64\cos^7x-112\cos^5x+56\cos^3x-7\cos x=\cos7x$.)

That means that, setting $x=\frac\pi7$, you'll have a polynomial in terms of $\cos\frac\pi7$ equal to $-1$. Now, just add $1$ to both sides, to get a polynomial in $\cos\frac\pi7$ equal to $0$, showing it's algebraic.

This works for any rational.