# Is the image of the function $\sin^2(x\pi)$ evaluated only with rational numbers a subset of the rational numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, real-numbers

Let $\sin^2(x\pi)$ be a function from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $A$ be the image of this function. Is it true that $A\subset\mathbb{Q}$?

In basic trigonometry classes we learn that $\sin{\frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $  and that $\sin{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. So in this case the property holds. Is it true $\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}$?

If not, is it possible to find all $x$ rational that do obey the rule and those $x$ rational that doesn't?

Comment: Be careful!! You do not calculate/evaluate the codomain of a function. In fact, it is part of the function itself.

Moreover, I think that you are mixing up the image of a function and the codomain of a function.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood that word. English is not my first language. Thank you!

Comment: As Matt's answer points out, this is not true. However, something similar but weaker is true: $\sin(\pi x)$ [is always algebraic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933177/proof-that-a-trigonometric-function-of-a-rational-angle-must-be-non-transcendent/1933276#1933276) (that is, the root of a polynomial). But in most cases, the polynomial in question is more complicated than it is for your two examples.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=1/8$ then this is false, as the resulting value is $\frac{2-\sqrt2}4$. I think this is the simplest value to see. This is not an isolated example; I'd say it fails to be rational for most values of $x$.

Comment: I see. Then is it possible to find all $x$ rational that do obey the rule and those $x$ rational that doesn't?

Comment: @Daif Probably, but I don't know the answer off the top of my head.

Comment: Only those few obvious ones work - use the double angle to transform the problem into the rationality of $\cos \pi q$ for rational $q$ and that is a well known result following from the Bernstein polynomials ($\cos n\pi q$ as a polynomial in $\cos \pi q$ and usual rational roots results)