# Are some trigonometric values transcendental?

Tags: trigonometry

We can express values for (e.g. 22,5° or 45° or 54°,90°....)  with a combination of square roots and basic calculating operations, however are they all expressible in such a way (=> are all algebraic?) Or are non-obvious  trigonometric values (e.g.  cos(3°)) transcendental numbers?

With very poor math skills, these are my thoughs on values that are not multiples of 5 or are already known for being algebraic.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Trig functions of rational multiples of $\pi$ are all algebraic (but not all expressible in radicals), trig functions of rational numbers (in radians) are transcendental (except for trivial, like $0$). $\pi$ radians is equal to $180$ degrees, just in case

Comment: You may find [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986231/is-a-trigonometric-function-applied-to-a-rational-multiple-of-pi-always-algeb) relevant

Comment: Thank you both so much! I found the link very releant indeed!